# Resizing canvas as screen changes size

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How do you make it so canvas is responsive to a user resizing the screen? Just using window.innerHeight/Width makes it full screen but the screen isn't responsive which is what I need. Also can you create a function within a function and recall it later?

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function screenSize() {
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  }

});


window.addEventListener('resize', screenSize);
```

Comment: `screenSize` is scoped inside the arrow function.  Move it outside, which will require you to fix the scoping of the canvas element.

Comment: Otherwise, put your resize event binding inside your load event handler

Comment: You might also consider using `vw` and `vh` units on your width and height instead, and let the browser take care of the resizing for you.

Answer (score 0):

option1) change your load event listner to this and remove your resize event listener

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function screenSize() {
    canvas.height = "100vh";
    canvas.width = "100vw";
  }
});
```

options2) define your screenSize function out of load event listner

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   const canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
});

function screenSize () {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

window.addEventListner("resize", screenSize)
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!